# Both fields are equal to null value, can't display error message

Tags: php

I'm developing a booking system, customers can book a maximum of 3 seats. If they book only 1 seat, this means that the 2 other seat values are set to null, when I submit the form I check it to make sure a customer isn't trying to double book the same seat, as you will see in the code below, so if the customer buys 1 seat, they'll get an error because both seats are equal to null, how can I solve this? Thanks

```
if($seat1==$seat2 || $seat2==$seat3 || $seat1==$seat3){
echo("You're trying to book the same seat numerous times, please go back.");
die();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use arrays. They can have as many values as you like, so you don't have a limit of 3, although you could enforce it still. And while you're at it, you can use a class as well. Just for the fun of it. ;)

```
$mrA = new User("GolezTrol");
$mrB = new User("user1715417");

try {

    $booking = new Booking();
    $booking->bookSeat($mrA, 'A7');
    $booking->bookSeat($mrA, 'A8');
    // $booking->bookSeat($mrB, 'A8'); // Double booking
    $booking->bookSeat($mrB, 'A9');
    $booking->bookSeat($mrA, 'B7');
    // $booking->bookSeat($mrA, 'B8'); // Only 3 seats allowed per user
    $booking->bookSeat($mrB, 'B9');
    // $booking->bookSeat($mrB, 'C7'); // No Seat Left

    var_dump($booking->bookedSeats); // Output Booking

} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    echo $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
array
  'GolezTrol' => 
    array
      0 => string 'A7' (length=2)
      1 => string 'A8' (length=2)
      2 => string 'B7' (length=2)
  'user1715417' => 
    array
      0 => string 'A9' (length=2)
      1 => string 'B9' (length=2)
```

Class Used

```
class User {
    public $id;

    function __construct($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    function __toString() {
        return $this->id;
    }
}

class Booking {
    public $bookedSeats = array();
    public $seatUsed = array();
    private $maxSeat = 5;
    private $maxBooking = 3;

    public function bookSeat(User $user, $seat) {
        if (count($this->seatUsed) >= $this->maxSeat) {
            throw new Exception('No Seat Left');
        }

        if (in_array($seat, $this->seatUsed)) {
            throw new Exception('Double booking');
        }

        if (array_key_exists($user->id, $this->bookedSeats)) {
            if (count($this->bookedSeats[$user->id]) >= $this->maxBooking) {
                throw new Exception('Only 3 seats allowed');
            }

            $this->bookedSeats[$user->id][] = $seat;
            $this->seatUsed[] = $seat;
        } else {
            $this->bookedSeats[$user->id] = array();
            $this->bookedSeats[$user->id][] = $seat;
            $this->seatUsed[] = $seat;
        }
    }
}
```

You can see how easy it would be to put the limit at 5 or 8 seats, without having to modify anything but a number, while your current check is already complex and will become twice as complex if you grow from 3 to 5.

Comment: Quick one .. why are you  using `array_search` instead of `in_array` ??

Comment: @Baba No particular reason. I don't use PHP very often, and I don't have a complete list of array functions ready in my mind. I looked one up on PHP.net and picked `array_search`, which does the trick. But `in_array` is the better choice, so I modified the code.

Comment: `elsif (count($this->bookedSeats) = 3)` is also not valid ..... :)

Comment: You're right again. It's getting late here. ;)

Comment: Cool .. Can i update your code  ??

Comment: Sure. You found another error? :)

Comment: I see. :) Now I want to upvote your code, but I can't. ;)

Comment: Lol .. you can not ... 100% credit goes to you ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the obvious answer, I'll let someone else be flashy and swish :)

```
if ( $seat1 === $seat2 || $seat1 === $seat3 || ($seat2 !== null && $seat2 === $seat3) )
```